# AJAX call not working(Error 302) Magento

Tags: php, magento, rest

I am trying to make an AJAX call to PHP webservice in Magento. Here's my PHP code snippet.

```
    <?php 
$callbackUrl = "http://localhost/magento/webservices/NewCustomer1.php";
    //intiate oauth callback URL
    $temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl = "http://localhost/magento/oauth/initiate?oauth_callback=". urlencode($callbackUrl);
    $adminAuthorizationUrl = 'http://localhost/magento/admin/oauth_authorize';
    $accessTokenRequestUrl = 'http://localhost/magento/oauth/token';
    //Magento rest API URL
    $apiUrl = 'http://localhost/magento/api/rest';
    //Consumer key and secret
    $consumerKey = 's3xt7w8lwhfrrfzrfvwm3lrilkf66d5n';
    $consumerSecret = 'vr3eq1x899pz1cf4zzxjzx3q03t66r3n';
    //get customer attributes
    $firstname=$_POST['fname'];
    $lastname=$_POST['lname'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
.......
```

Here's my jquery

```
 $('#btnSubmit').click(function(){
    console.log("Submit Clicked");
    var fName=$('#firstname').val();
    var lName=$('#lastname').val();
    var email=$('#email_address').val();
    var password=$('#password').val();
    var pass_conf=$('#confirmation').val();
    var dataString = 'fname='+ fName + '&lname=' + lName + '&email=' + email + '&password=' +password+ '&webid=1&groupid=1';
    /*http://localhost/magento/webservices/Newcustomer1.php?fname=siri&lname=s&email=siri@abc.com&password=password123&webid=1&groupid=1*/
    //your validation code
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/magento/webservices/Newcustomer1.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: dataString, 
        success: function(data) {
            $('#message').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

On submitting am getting 302 Found error. It works if I pass parameters in URL itself and change $_REQUEST to $_GET.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 302 Found occurs if the requested URL respond with an invitation for redirection. My guess is that occurs while you're trying to authenticate...

Answer (score 0):

Hey here is what you should do.

Give your form where the value that you need to send an ID ex :

```
<form id ="myfrom" >
```

Now in your ajax call do the following, instead of

```
data: dataString,
```

do

```
data : $('#myform').serialize() ,
```

Let me know if that fixes it.
And in the PHP part i sugest that first you do

```
print_r($_POST);
```

just so you see how the data is passed.

Comment: @Marwan-I need to pass additional parameters as well, so I can't use serialize. I guess this issue is cause of OAuth authentication.